# simplexml get value of node that is next to matched node

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I am wondering if I can get a neighboring node's value

```
<item>
   <title>Cell Phone Plans That Make You Go Hmmm</title> 
   <link>http://www.articlegeek.com/computers/telecommunication_articles/10574-    cellphoneplanst.htm</link> 
    <description>Cell phone plans across the globe vary a great deal. Some say that cell phone  plans in the US are more costly. However, there are some advantages to the cell phone plans in the US which may balance the difference.</description> 
</item>
```

This is my query to get the description content but I want the link as well that matches the description.

```
    $userIN = "cell";
    $nod2 = $xml->xpath 
  ("//description
              [text( 
                [contains
                 (translate(.,'ABCDEFGHJIKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 'abcdefghjiklmnopqrstuvwxyz'),
                   '".$userIN."')]]");
```

Comment: As you start to become a pro with xpath already, you probably want to learn about axes next: [XPath axes - XPath (Schlitt & Westhoff)](http://schlitt.info/opensource/blog/0704_xpath.html#xpath-axes)

Comment: See http://zvon.org/xxl/XPathTutorial/Output/example15.html

Comment: curious: what is this xpath expression doing? looking for a `<description>` node containing `cell` and replacing all uppercase to lowercase? Why doing it this way?

Comment: It's the only way I know of. I am new to this. I want the description matches in addition to the next node.

Comment: I'm making it case insensitive in a way so I don't miss something

Answer (score 0):

I Borrowed this answer from another topic:

[SimpleXML get next/prev node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3989226/simplexml-get-next-prev-node)

Hope this helps.

```
$xmlData = new SimpleXMLElement(file_get_contents("data.xml"));
$index = 0;
foreach($xmlData->row as $item) {
    if ($item->url == $_GET['id']) {
        // show photo
        $title = $item->title;

        $prev = $xmlData->row[$index-1];
        $next = $xmlData->row[$index+1];
    }
    $index++;
}
```